# SSRS expression and free text in the same textbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible?

I would like to place the following inside a textbox:

```
There are =Count("MyDataSet") records found.
```

But if I place that in the expression on the textbox it just displays as above instead of getting the value.

Now I know if I were to split the above in two different textbox works ok but for spacing reasons it would be better if I could just use one?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an expression in the textbox that specifies the text strings and concatenates these to your count value, something like:

```
="There are " & CountRows("MyDataSet") & " records found"
```